# $event in AngularDart 1.0 is not available anymore - what is the alternative?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Pre AngularDart 1.0 I used something like
`<button on-click="handleClearClicked($event)">Clear</button>`

$event is not available anymore. I get

...has no instance getter '$event'.
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '$event'

What is the alternative?

Comment: I haven't read anything about it being discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

Ha - found the answer.

Pre Angular 1.0 it worked with on-click now it has to be **ng-click**

So I changed the sample from above to:

```dart
<button ng-click="handleClearClicked($event)">Clear</button>
```

and voila - $event ist back again.
 
(not sure if this is a bug or a feature - but anyway, it works)