# Sending some event info from a child component to the parent component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to pass a int value from a child component to its parent component. The event itself arrives properly but I do fail on adding an Event parameter in the receiving method of the parent.

**UPDATE:** edited code to shrunk down, but complete example

---

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';

class MyItem {
  int id = 1;
}



@Component(
    selector: 'my-list',
    directives: const [MyListItem],
    template: '''
<div *ngFor='let myItem of myItems'>
  <my-list-item [myItem]='myItem' (dirtiesParent)='doInit($event)'></my-list-item>
</div>
''')
class MyList {

  @Input()
  List<MyItem> myItems = [ new MyItem() ];

  void doInit() {
    print("got event");
  }

}



@Component(
    selector: 'my-list-item',
    template: '''
<div>id {{myItem.id}}<button (click)='doDelete()'>delete</button></div>
''')
class MyListItem {

  @Input()
  MyItem myItem;
  @Output()
  EventEmitter<int> dirtiesParent = new EventEmitter();

  void doDelete() {
    dirtiesParent.add(myItem.id);
  }

}
```

Comment: are you trying to get doDeleteEntry to accept the entry id as a parameter? does `(onDelete)="doDeleteEntry($event)"` work?

Comment: Yes, I want to do exactly that. On doing so as you described even the compiler complains with the message

`Build error: Transform DirectiveProcessor on dart4|lib/entry/entry_component.dart threw error: Angular 2 could not understand the value in View#template. `
<material-expansionpanel-set *ngFor="let entry of entries">
  <entry-...
`

Comment: Can you please post the source (dart and html) of `entry_component.dart`?

Comment: I added the source

Comment: I don't tink the error is related to the code in your question. Where do you have `<material-expansionpanel-set *ngFor="let entry of entries"> <entry-... `?

Comment: sorry, the error message I posted in the comment does not fit to above updated code (which I shrunk for readability) - with the updated code I run still in the compile error.

Comment: What do you mean by "fail on adding an Event parameter in the receiving method. What about `void doInit(int event) { print("got event $event");`?

Comment: I get `EXCEPTION: Error in asset:moquid/lib/entry/entry_component.dart class EntryList - inline template:1:35`.

Comment: How is the color of "$event" in your IDE ? Is he trying to evaluate it ?

Take a look at this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385952/angular-2-could-not-understand-the-value-in-viewtemplate-using-event

and do like Günter said
`void doInit(int event) { print("got event $event");`

Comment: thx @HadrienLejard => escaping the $event did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just improperly escaped the `$`. Try this:

```
class MyItem {
  int id = 1;
}

@Component(
    selector: 'my-list',
    directives: const [MyListItem],
    template: '''
<div *ngFor='let myItem of myItems'>
  <my-list-item [myItem]='myItem' (dirtiesParent)='doInit(\$event)'></my-list-item>
</div>
''')
class MyList {
  @Input()
  List<MyItem> myItems = [new MyItem()];

  void doInit(int id) {
    print("got event for id $id");
  }
}

@Component(
    selector: 'my-list-item',
    template: '''
<div>id {{myItem.id}}<button (click)='doDelete()'>delete</button></div>
''')
class MyListItem {
  @Input()
  MyItem myItem;
  @Output()
  EventEmitter<int> dirtiesParent = new EventEmitter();

  void doDelete() {
    dirtiesParent.add(myItem.id);
  }
}
```

This works for me (it prints "got event for id 1"). Note that I also added the expected parameter to `doInit()`.

Comment: I'm surprised that your editor didn't scream about the unescaped `$`. If I may ask: what editor do you use and do you have a Dart plugin installed?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ with the Dart Plugin installed. I got no hint from the IDE that the escacpe char is missing.